# Why doesn't this function properly forward one NetworkStream to another?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcp

I'm trying to make a simple TCP forwarder as an exercise in C#. This is the function I'm using to forward one TCP stream to another:

```
public static void forward (NetworkStream stm1, NetworkStream stm2)
{
    new Thread (new ThreadStart(() =>{
    try{
        while (true) {
            int a = stm1.ReadByte ();
            if (a > 0) stm2.WriteByte ((byte)a);
        }
    }catch{
            stm1.Close();
            stm2.Close();
        }
    })).Start ();
    try {
        while (true) {
            int a = stm2.ReadByte ();
            if (a > 0)
                stm1.WriteByte ((byte)a);
        }
    } catch {
        stm1.Close ();
        stm2.Close ();
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work properly. Well, I can telnet things through it, but it

1. uses horrendous amounts of CPU
2. does not seem to be 8-bit clean, as it refuses to load images via HTTP properly.

How would I properly implement such a function?

Comment: `uses horrendous amounts of CPU 2`  -- Because your blocking in an infinite loop.

Comment: Sidenote: make sure not to just swallow errors. Also, try not to duplicate the code two times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zero is a perfectly valid byte... and a negative value from `ReadByte()` signals EOF:

```
int a = stm2.ReadByte();
if (a < 0) break;
stm1.WriteByte ((byte)a);
```

(etc)

However, writing in chunks would be far preferable:

```
stm2.CopyTo(stm1);
```

Comment: Note that I need bidirectional forwarding. Doing that would result in the response of the server not getting forwarded back to the client. I'm currently using `new Thread (new ThreadStart(()=>stm1.CopyTo (stm2))).Start ();
    stm2.CopyTo (stm1);` but this is obviously non-thread-safe and causes a whole lotta deadlocks.

Comment: @EricDong indeed, you'd either need to replace both with async code, or use two threads; I was sticking with the 2 threads approach - but simply: the code you have at the moment *is simply wrong*. I am implicitly assuming you would apply the above fix (whichever you prefer) to **both** locations, obviously reversing `stm1` / `stm2`. The Bad CPU usage is because you *aren't exiting either properly*.

Comment: @EricDong in the case of `NetworkStream`, the `Read` and `Write` are separate and can be used concurrently; it shouldn't cause deadlocks

Answer (score 1):

You are not exiting the loop. And you are reading one byte at a time.
Use this instead.

```
stm1.CopyTo(stm2);
```

Comment: This works both ways? Also, I'm trying to extend this to support SSL tunneling which requires manually twiddling with `TcpClient`s. Any suggestion on how to manually do everything?

Comment: And before you say anything, your code absolutely does not work ;( I cannot get any response from the server. Edit: Had to do it both ways in two threads.

Comment: You would have to write the reverse also of course. Not working how?